# apache-spark regex extract words from rdd

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I try to extract words from a textfile.

Textfile:

```
"Line1 with words to extract"
"Line2 with words to extract"
"Line3 with words to extract"
```

The following works well:

```
val data = sc.textFile(file_in).map(_.toLowerCase).cache()
val all = data.flatMap(a => "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn a)


scala> data.count
res14: Long = 3

scala> all.count
res11: Long = 1419
```

But I want to extract the words for every line.
If i type

```
val separated = data.map(line => line.flatMap(a => "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn a))
```

i get

```
scala> val separated = data.map(line => line.flatMap(a => "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn a))
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Char
 required: CharSequence
       val separated = data.map(line => line.flatMap(a => "[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn a))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? `line` is a `String` so if you try to `flatMap` it then `a` is a single char in that `String`, so you get the error that you see.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your Answer.

The goal was to count the occourence of words in a pos/neg-wordlist.

Seems this works:

```
// load inputfile 
val file_in = "/path/to/teststring.txt"
val data = sc.textFile(file_in).map(_.toLowerCase).cache()

// load wordlists
val pos_file = "/path/to/pos_list.txt"
val neg_file = "/path/to/neg_list.txt"
val pos_words = sc.textFile(pos_file).cache().collect().toSet
val neg_words = sc.textFile(neg_file).cache().collect().toSet

// RegEx
val regexpr = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r


val separated = data.map(line => regexpr.findAllIn(line).toList) 

// #_of_words - #_of_pos_words_ - #_of_neg_words
val counts = separated.map(list => (list.size,(list.filter(pos => pos_words contains pos)).size, (list.filter(neg => neg_words contains neg)).size))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not exactly Apache Spark, your first **map** will make you handle a line, but your **flatMap** on that line will make you iterate on the characters in this line **String**. So Spark or not, your code won't work, for example in a Scala REPL :

```
> val lines = List("Line1 with words to extract", 
                   "Line2 with words to extract", 
                   "Line3 with words to extract")

> lines.map( line => line.flatMap("[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn _)

  <console>:9: error: type mismatch;
    found   : Char
    required: CharSequence
```

So if you really want, using your regexp, all the words in your line, just use flatMap once :

```
 scala> lines.flatMap("[a-zA-Z]+".r findAllIn _)
        res: List[String] = List(Line, with, words, to, extract, Line, with, words, to, extract, Line, with, words, to, extract)
```

Regards,